# Get the filelist object when a file is selected Jquery

Tags: jquery, filelist

When dragging and dropping a file into `<div>` for getting the filelist object i used `var files=e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;` but when selecting a file from the upload window i do not know what to use.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qdJ2T/) jsfiddle.

What should I use to get the filelist from the `<input type="file">`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

any jQuery object have it's DOM element accessed using [], for example

```js
$('input[type=file]')[0].files;
```

To your fiddle, it would be:

```js
var files = this.files;
```

no need for jQuery in this case, because of the `change` event

See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qdJ2T/1/

Comment: This helped me out BIG TIME. All of the other posts I've been reading talked about the jQuery ajax upload process but none of them specified how to reference the actual file in the form. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

different methods to access the FileList object :

```
$("#btStartUpload").on("click", function(evt) {        

        var filesSelected = document.getElementById('btInput').files; // FileList object
        var filesSelected = $('#btInput').prop('files'); // with jQuery
        var filesSelected = $('#btInput')[0].files; // with jQuery
        var filesSelected = $('input[type=file]')[0].files;  // with jQuery
        console.log(filesSelected);

        // action
    });
```